# How can I determine if an algoritm can be expressed as a boolean circuit?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

Suppose I want to express Data Encryption Standard(DES) encryption algorithm as a boolean circuit. How can I determine if what I want is practical, and if it is how can I do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to do that in order to evaluate DES decryption circuit homomorphically, as it was done for AES in this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/099.pdf

Comment: Every finite function can be expressed as a circuit. If the function can be computed efficiently, then we can find a small circuit computing the function.